# Can't find abandoned memory

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, memory-management

AgentDashboardNavigationController LIVES!

I keep stepping through the same procedure, whereby the agentDashboardNavigationController VC in my tabBarController is replaced by an editing interface VC.

On completion, the editing interface is replaced with a new agentDashboardNavigationController.

For some reason the number of living agentDashboardNavigationController objects keeps rising.

Basically I flip back and forth what lives in that one tab by replacing the object in a mutable copy of the view controllers.

agentDashboardNavigationController is swapped in:

```
NSMutableArray *newViewControllers = [self.mainTabBarController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
AgentDashboardNavigationController *agentDashboardNavigationController = [[AgentDashboardNavigationController alloc] init];
// cycle through until we find the agentcontroller and remove it
// for now that's the only controller that gets removed so we break
NSUInteger index = [newViewControllers indexOfObjectPassingTest: ^ BOOL (id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[obj tabBarItem].title isEqualToString:@"Guest Card"];
}];

[newViewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:agentDashboardNavigationController];
[self.mainTabBarController setViewControllers:newViewControllers animated:NO];

[newViewControllers release];

[agentDashboardNavigationController release];
```

and its swapped out:

```
UISplitViewController *splitVC = self.guestCardManagementController.splitViewController;

// remove agentTab
NSMutableArray *newViewControllers = [self.mainTabBarController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

// cycle through until we find the agentcontroller and remove it
NSUInteger index = [newViewControllers indexOfObjectPassingTest: ^ BOOL (id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj class] == [AgentDashboardNavigationController class];
}];
[newViewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:splitVC];
[self.mainTabBarController setViewControllers:newViewControllers animated:NO];
[newViewControllers release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Scratch that. The problem was a retain cycle. Once I realized I should tick on the 'record reference counts' bit, I could see its child was retaining it!

My first one of those. Man those are a pain to solve.